# Error al instalar firebase en angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firestore, module.exports

Alguien me podrá ayudar con este problema se que es muy corto esta pregunta, pero necesitaria de su ayuda.

Tengo este error:

El módulo '"@angular/fire/auth"' no tiene ningún miembro 'AngularFireAuthModule' exportado.Bueno y asi con cada error segun la imagen mas abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar a instalarlo corectamente. solo agrege ***npm install firebase @angular/fire --save*** nose si tengo que instalar algo mas ?

Comment: Si ejecutas `ng build` ¿Se compila la aplicación?

Comment: hola buen dian, si si.

Comment: Si la aplicación compila desde la consola es porque todo está bien a nivel de código. Parece ser el IDE el que está reportando errores falsos prueba reiniciándolo.

Comment: sigue igual ya probe

Answer (score 0):

para conectar firebase con angular15 te recomiendes que crees la carpeta environments te paras en la raiz y colocas ng generate environments, y ya habiendo creado el proyecto en firebase ejecutas:
1 tenes que conectar tu cuenta de firebase con= firebase login
2 luego comprueba si la conexion esta bien y listas los proyectos= firebase project:list
3 luego inicializas firebase con= firebase init
4 y ahora agrega el siguente comando= ng add@angular/fire